# My CNN classifier gives wrong prediction on random images

Tags: tensorflow, classification, conv-neural-network

I trained my CNN classifier (using tensorflow) with 3 data categories (ID card, passport, bills).
When I test it with images that belong to one of the 3 categories, it gives the right prediction. However, when I test it with a wrong image (a car image for example) it keeps giving me prediction (i.e. it predicts that the car belongs the ID card category).

**Is there a way to make it display an error message instead of giving a wrong prediction?**

Comment: Not really, this is more of a research problem than a programming one.

Comment: To be more precise, you can use techniques like https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.04865 to detect Out of Distribution examples, but as I said, its more complicated than just a programming problem.

Comment: What I know about prediction is that the classifier, given an image to predict, will see which is the closest category to put that image in. So in other words, the classifier assumes that the given image must belong to one of the categories that it was trained on, so it will just give a probability.
Am I right?

Comment: Yes, the classifier doesn't know about any other categories, and it does not have to predict the most similar category, its pretty much random. With the probabilities you cannot generally detect this because they are not calibrated for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you @MatiasValdenegro, please post an answer summarizing your comments so that others who have the same problem find it in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be tackled differently. This is known as **open set recognition problem**. You can google it and find more about it but basically it's this: 
You cannot train your classifier on every class imaginable. It will always run into some other class that it's not familiar with and that it hasn't already seen before.

There are a few solutions from which I will single out the 3 of them:

1. **Separate binary classifier** - You can build separate binary classifier that recognizes images and sorts them in two categories depending on if the bill, passport or ID are in the image or not. If they are, it should let the algorithm you have already build to process the image and classify it into one of the 3 categories. If the first classifier says that some other object is in the image, you can immediately discard the image because it's not the image of bill/passport/ID.
2. **Thresholding**. In the case when the ID is on the image, probability of the ID is high and probabilities for bill and passport are fairly low. In the case when the image is something else (ex. *a car*), the probabilities are most probably about the same for all 3 classes. In other words, probability for neither of the classes really stand out. That is a situation in which you pick the highest probability of the ones generated and set the output class to be the class of that probability, regardless the value of probability is 0.4 or something like that. To resolve this, you can set a threshold at, let's say 0.7, and say if neither of probabilities is over that threshold, there is something else on the picture (not ID, passport or bill).
3. Create the fourth class: **Unknown**. If you pick this option, you should add few of the other images to the dataset and label them *unknown*. Then train the classifier and see what the result is.

I would recommend 1 or 2. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.
The first method sounds good for me.
I am afraid the second method is not suitable for my problem, because even with wrong images, the probability is high (  more than 90% sometimes)
As for the third method, as you said "You cannot train your classifier on every class imaginable. It will always run into some other class that it's not familiar with and that it hasn't already seen before." so it is not very effective I guess.
I will try the first method.
Thank you again for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Why do you not recommend the last option ? Is it less effective ?  
Is there any fundamental different between option #1 and #3 ?

Answer (score 4):

This is not really a programming problem, its way more complicated. What you want is called Out of Distribution detection, where the classifier has a way to tell you that the sample is not on the training set.

There are recent research papers that deal with this problem, such as https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.04865 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.09325

In general you cannot use a model that has not been trained specifically for this, for example, the probabilities produced by a softmax classifier are not calibrated for this purpose, so thresholding these probabilities will not work at all.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way is to simply add a fourth category for anything but the other three and train it with various completely random photos.

Comment: I thought about it, but it is not effective because it is like the fourth category will contain **ANY OTHER THING** except the ID cards, bills and passports.

Comment: It should certainly make it easier to disregard results though, as if the fourth output is >0.5 and the others are all about equal or none of them particularly stand out then you can take as none of the above.

Comment: Yes, right, if you take it from the mathematical side (probability), if you test the model with a random image, the highest probability will probably be for the fourth category since it is contains random images. 
This is the easiest method to to start with.

Comment: Yeh, but as you did, I would definitely recommend referring to the answer you marked, it's much better haha

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for same solution and it brought me here. To solve this, I used [math.isclose()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) function to compare the values of my prediction.

```
def check_distribution(self, prediction):
    checker = [x for x in prediction[0] if math.isclose(1, x, abs_tol=1e-9) ]
    for probability in prediction[0]:
        if len(checker) > 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Feel free to alter the abs_tol parameter depending on how brutal you want to be.