# How to prepare images to train a ConvNet with Python/Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, classification, conv-neural-network

Attempting to train a cnn (convolutional neural network) using Python + Keras.  But even the simplest questions seem to be difficult to answer, and the tutorials out there don't have the answers I seek.

I have access to many thousands of images of a handful of classes I want to recognize.  But how do I prepare the images?  For example:

1. Should the images be cropped to *exactly* the object I want to recognize?  The objects in this case are perfectly rectangular, so I could crop them to be perfect if that helps training.
2. What size should the images be?  Do I keep them at high-resolution, or do I resize them to be small?  Lots of examples with things like MNIST which uses images of 18x18 pixels, but at that size objects of these classes are a meaningless blur, all resembling each other.
3. During training, should I only have images with the classes I want to identify?  Or should I insert into the mix some images of other things I don't care about?
4. During training, is it OK to have multiple instances of the object in a single image?  Or should I limit the training images to ones where there is only 1 object of a single class?

---

Edit:  Was asked about whether or not I need to know where the object is located.  The answer is I need to do object detection:

[image: classification vs semantic segmentation vs object detection vs instance segmentation]

(That image was taken from a [blog post](https://engineering.matterport.com/splash-of-color-instance-segmentation-with-mask-r-cnn-and-tensorflow-7c761e238b46) about Mask-RCNN, but my question is more newbie than that, it isn't specific to Mask-RCNN.)

Comment: Are you just interested to classify the images (e.g. it's an image of chair, dog, cat, tree, lamp, etc), or do you also want to find the location of the object in the image as well?

Comment: I wrote my answer having image classification in mind; but I think most of it are general and applicable to classification, object detection or even segmentation. For example, in the final part I mentioned VGG because I had classification in mind. Instead, you can consider object detection models like [YOLO](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/) as the base of your model (e.g. see [this](https://www.powu3.com/ml/yolo/) or [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-perform-object-detection-with-yolov3-in-keras/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is that to start small and simple: start with employing common configs/parameters/methods and change them as needed based on the results of experiments you would perform.

> 1. Should the images be cropped to exactly the object I want to recognize? The objects in this case are perfectly rectangular, so I could crop them to be perfect if that helps training.

No, not necessarily. Actually, it would be better to not do that because when you want to use your model in real world the images are not perfectly cropped. For example, suppose you have taken the following picture in your room:

[image: image of a chair in the room]

You expect your model to predict "chair" as the output, although there are other things in background. Hence your model would be much more applicable/robust on a wide range of images found in real world which may have clutter in the background. Further, it's not the case that we always have the coordinates of the box surrounding the object to crop it out.

> 2. What size should the images be? Do I keep them at high-resolution, or do I resize them to be small? Lots of examples with things like MNIST which uses images of 18x18 pixels, but at that size objects of these classes are a meaningless blur, all resembling each other.

Stick to common sizes used for images. For example, most of the models trained on ImageNet take images of size 224x224 as input. Keep in mind that the larger the images, the training of the model would be much more computationally involved and therefore it would take much more time to be trained. Generally, the smaller the better as long as you would not lose too much information/quality of the image after resizing.

> 3. During training, should I only have images with the classes I want to identify? Or should I insert into the mix some images of other things I don't care about?

Usually, we only have images from the known classes which we want to classify and do not consider a "others" class. However, if you are interested that your model to be able to categorize unknown images as one class (note that a model trained on images of only dogs and cats, sees and classify everything as dog and cat even if you give it an image of chair or a tree or an oven), you can add another "unknown"/"others" class and assign all the images with no class associated to them to that class. But, after training is finished, you should NOT expect that your model can **perfectly** recognize any unknown object and predict it as "unknown" class (i.e. mainly because the images belonging to "unknown" class are so much varied that you cannot represent them with just hundreds or thousands examples of unknown images).

> 4. During training, is it OK to have multiple instances of the object in a single image? Or should I limit the training images to ones where there is only 1 object of a single class?

I don't think having multiple instances of the same object in an image would make any problems, mainly due to the fact that CNNs are translation-invariant and therefore if a feature is detected in a region of image it could be detected somewhere else in the image (which may belong to another instance of the object). It might even increase the accuracy of the model if you have a mix of single-instance and multiple-instance images in your training data.

As a final note, I suggest you to not train a CNN classification model from scratch. There are already very good models trained on ImageNet and therefore you can use the knowledge already extracted by and accumulated in these models (i.e. this approach is called "transfer learning", i.e you transform knowledge from one domain/model to another domain/model). For example, you can use VGG16 as the base of your model and just change the top layers (or only the classifier layer). This way the training not only would be much faster (because the base is already trained and at least the low-level features such as edges or textures are mostly share between all the images we see), but also it would be much more accurate (because the base has been already trained on thousands of images). I suggest you to read this [official tutorial from Keras blog](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) which illustrates using this kind of training.

Answer (score 1):

To answer each of your questions:

1. No, because when testing, that isn't what the network will be receiving. It will be receiving an image with the object at some location, surrounded by a lot of noise, so it's best you train it to cope with that.
2. As low a resolution as you can afford while the images are still differentiable to you. If you can tell them apart, then the resolution is ok. The reason for a low resolution is to reduce complexity and increase the number of epochs/time
3. this is up to you, it depends on whether you think this network will actually receive an input that is totally random. If you would like to know some ways of dealing with this, see here: [My CNN classifier gives wrong prediction on random images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52831038/my-cnn-classifier-gives-wrong-prediction-on-random)
4. Yes, so long as it occurs multiple times during training and isn't an outlier. You want your training data to be as uniform as possible, so ideally if there are multiple objects sometimes, and only one other times, there should be an equal number of training images for both of these cases so the network learns uniformly.

Other ways to prepare:

- Sometimes taking the greyscale of an image can help by decreasing
  complexity.
- Centralising the data (by taking the mean pixel value for every pixel
  across the entire data set and subtracting it from each pixel) can
  also help.